# Can't figure out what kind of transformer I need

Tags: transformer

I am doing some beginner project through YouTube and some books. So now I need a transformer which primary side has 3 wires while secondary side has only 2 wire. It consists 40 0mH coil(called the primary) and 2 mH coil (called the secondary) wrapped around an iron bar.
For better understanding I have given a schematic of a particular small project
[image: schematic]
So what kind of transformer this is?
And what will be the other numbers?

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question because you haven't told us what you are building. Post the schematic or draw one using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: audio transformer .... are you sure that the top 1/2 of the primary winding is shorted out?

Comment: You still haven't told us what you are building. At best that circuit will cause a click on the loudspeaker when you turn it on. The dot in the top right will short-circuit the top half of the primary. The circuit looks rubbish and the instructions seem to be rubbish too so I think you should find a better project.

Comment: Looks like a simple demonstration of impedance time constants and cone pops. For no useful result that you can make on Falstad simulator for electronics . Choose n turns ratio to step down inductance ratio by turns ratio n^2 for a current boost ratio of n and lower voltage ratio of n. With some coupling factor <1 and other stuff

Comment: This circuit is a good example of a project which has a **very low chance of actually working** as a lot depends on the transformer, which isn't specified clearly, which comes in many variations and only some might work. So you'll get frustrated about electronics and give up. And that's exactly the opposite of what we want. So **find a better project**.

Comment: Second that, this circuit requires the tinkering of a very experienced person with measuring equipment and a lot of spare parts to play with to make it work.

Comment: After removing the short circuit dot between the transformer and the power switch, this can be a musical instrument which has plenty of different pitches and maybe tones, too. It's played by moving the loose wires with both hands. It's not especially perfect for traditional western music, but propellerhead artists and people from other cultures can find it very useful. The transformer has useful spesifications - the inductances. Unfortunately hobbyists rarely have inductance meters nor math knowledge to work around it. Do something easier - inductances are a nightmare for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

ZL1/ZL2= 20

On your previous question the small AC per transformer will work using the centre tap and one side only like this schematic.

240V/12V means Z1/Z2= 20:1 inductance ratio.  To lower the source impedance of caps to speaker and thus drive more current force on cone.

The voltage ratios are the same except your source 9Vdc with limited current